# Java Iterator: What does it mean :java.util.ArrayList$Itr

Tags: java, collections

There is code :

```java
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>() ;
Iterator iterator = al.iterator();
System.out.println(iterator.getClass().getName());
```

I get :

```
 java.util.ArrayList$Itr
```

What does it mean: "ArrayList$Itr" ?

What implementation of Iterator i get in this line ?

```
Iterator iterator = al.iterator();
```

Comment: It's an implementation class. Which implementation of Iterator you get when you call the `iterator()` method on an `ArrayList` is not part of the API contract - so it's not relevant for you what class it is. You just need to know that it will follow the contract of `Iterator`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the `ArrayList` class, the following inner class is defined:

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {...}
```

`al.iterator()` returns an instance of that class, whose full name is `java.util.ArrayList$Itr`.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.ArrayList` has internal `private class Itr implements Iterator<E>` defined inside `ArrayList` which is returned when you call `list.iterator()` method.

Refer internal implementation of `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean: "ArrayList$Itr" ?

This means `Itr` is an inner class of `ArrayList`.

> What implementation of Iterator i get in this line?

The implementation you will get is (as of now) `java.util.ArrayList$Itr`. But you should not rely on this specific implementation as this is not part of the API of `ArrayList` and might change in future versions of Java. The only thing you can rely on is that you will get an `Iterator`.